# REST API defaultValues what is stand for?

Tags: rest-api

What is *recordTypeId* ? and what this endpoint stand for?

```
/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Entity(Lead, Account, etc.)/defaultValues?recordTypeId
```

may be it is something obvious, but I could not find an accurate related info.

[image]

Comment: `services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/object/quickActions/{action name}/defaultValues/
`?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation or web page where you found this endpoint? As far as I can tell, it does not exist.

Comment: it exists , screenshot added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's weird, but I can't find this resource in the documentation, nor can I get this to work in the Workbench (v42.0); it's possible that this is a leaked resource from v43.0 (Summer '18). Presumably, this end point will allow us to get the default values for a specific record type, where recordTypeId is the record type to use, and fields are the fields you are interested in getting the default values for. For example, if this endpoint worked, you'd be able to determine the default value for Account Industry using a URL like the following:

```
/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/defaultValues?recordTypeId=01250000000QbbwAAC&fields=Industry
```

However, since it doesn't currently appear to be working, you'll probably want to use the Describe Layout resource:

```
/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/describe/layouts/01250000000QbbwAAC
```

This will give you all of the fields that are valid for the current page layout and their default values, if any.